# How do you scrape fields for auto-tagging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a form with a large textarea and a couple text fields.  We also have a list of 1500 tags (some have spaces) categorized in 5 types.  What is the best way to scrape the text entered by users to extract tags that they may have entered.

We do not want to give them a tag field - it needs to happen automatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want ideas, front-end or back-end wise? You should be a bit clearer with this since you mention Ruby on Rails which is back-end related and Javascript/jQuery which is front-end related.

Comment: What I am looking for is a solution if a user is filling in a detailed description and not thinking about "tags".  My audience is not a techie one and they like to write long form, not type in keywords.  What we are looking to do is allow them to do this and parse/scrape the long-form text for our tags.  Whether its a Javascript or AJAX to ruby solution is irrelevant.

Comment: Going to make a completely new answer then; since the one I made is a good approach for tagging related issues.

Answer (score 1):

### Front-end wise:

I would suggest you using one of the available autocompletion jquery plugins (there are many, just google around) that does an AJAX request per tag, returning a JSON object with the similar tags. To do this you'll need to make a route where you can query; example: http://mysite.com/tags?s=%s which returns JSON.

The other way to do it, the **lazy** way, which is doable considering the amount of tags you have (and of course depending if this is something users can view) is outputing the whole tag array as a JSON object embeded on the document. I don't recommend this unless you're in a really urge to solve the problem and you don't mind loading extra amount of stuff.

The tags should be separated by commas.

### Back-end wise:

Once you submit the form you'll need to add an extra procedure to parse the given tags. Just do a `tags.split(',')` and you'll get a tag array which you can later iterate over to insert the data into the database.

Comment: +1 for the front-end approach. It's much better to start with a good seed pile of tags for users to pick from, rather than allow random and arbitrary submissions. Keep track of the tags that get used most, and slowly remove the ones that never get used. At the same time, have a submit-a-tag mechanism to vet unworthy suggestions. Humans, being humans, will misspell tags, or deliberately inject words that don't belong.

Comment: This sounds like classic tagging to me and is not an option.  The tagging needs to be hidden from users.

Comment: +1 to the Tin Man for expressing a good point in implementing records inline.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, one solution could be this:

1. On application load, build a Set with all the tags.
2. When a user posts a text, iterate through all the words and check them against the Set.

This would be pretty fast for your purpose, considering looking up in a Set takes constant time.

If a word is included in your tag-set, add the word to a new Set. When done iterating through all the words, do the database queries to associate the new tags with the uploaded text.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonably simple approach. Only iterating through all the entered words will not find multi-word tags. You should instead iterate through all the tags (however many words they have) and check them against the whole entered text. If there's a match, you can add that tag to your list.

Comment: @pixelistik is correct. This will not work with multi-word tags (I missed that you wrote "some tags have spaces"). In the case of multi-word tags, you could iterate over all the tags and do a regex on the text. Unfortunately, this now takes number_of_tags * O(N).

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand this right.

You could use regex, but I am not sure about its efficiency when working with 1500 match-able results (if you can define multiple tags in a single regex statement that would be good).

```
for(var index = 0; index < textAreas.length; index++)
{
    textAreas[index].innerHTML.match(new Regex("/" + tags + "/", g));  //will return an array of the found tags.
}

//Where Tags is in the format tag1|tag2|tag3
//Where tagN can be a regex that matches multiple tags in your list.
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't edit my previous answer since this one is a completely different approach to the one proposed; and editing it would mean remaking it, which is a bad idea considering the answer may be useful to someone.

One way to make "auto tagging", in the sense that you never tell your people to write a single keyword, is to parse the content being aware of the context (for instance, if your people will write about Bikes, you need to avoid ignoring those words).

To begin with the content:

- Remove Pronouns
- Remove Common Names (non-related)
- Remove Conjunctions
- Remove Prepositions
- Remove addresses (but take the word that is linked)
- Split all the words remaining words, and weight them based on appearance.
- Give more weight to words that are linked or that appear on the title tag.

This should be done on the back-end; since the odds are you're going to be doing a lot of preparing. Removing HTML at especial points, iterate through arrays, weight the words and sanitize them.